# Set height dropdownlist telerik?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with control telerik MVC. I have two dropdownlist A,B,I want to set height dropdownlist A I see once dropdownlist has style 't-popup' but I can not set it in javascript . Can you help me this issue . Thank in advance

Comment: You could check on this -> http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-maximum-dropdown-height

Comment: I only want to set height the current choice combobox.if using way above topic, it will impress to other combobox`s height